# "I'd very much" instead of "I'd rather"

Tags: meaning, grammar

The other day, I heard someone saying, "I'd very much say the opposite."

Is that the alternative way to say "I'd rather say" or is it just one of those non-native concoctions?

Comment: What do you mean by "non-native concoctions?" I'm certain every native English speaker is familiar with both of these constructions. (Though the first is more common in the UK, as I understand it.)

Comment: Oh I just wanted to make sure that it belongs in regular English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'd very much [...]* is the same as saying *I'd be inclined to [...]* since inclination involves holding something with greater respect.

*I'd rather [...]* implies a trade-off between two options — the inclination to do something *and* the declination to do something else because of this.

So these two phrases do not necessarily mean the same thing. Though, loosely, they could be similar to most people in a casual conversation.

Comment: In my opinion the phrase "I'd very much say" expresses not just inclination away from a point of view but a firm conviction against it. If someone said "I'd rather say X" or "I'd be inclined to say X" to me then I would expect there to be a possibility that they could be swayed to the opposite view by argument, if they said "I'd very much say X" then I would expect their view to be much less amenable to conversion.

Answer (score 0):

**"Would" is a verb.**

"I'd" is, as you know, a contraction of "I would." Though its use as a standalone is unusual in modern American English ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/would) marks it as archaic), phrases like your first example are still a commonality in British English, by my understanding.

In the first sentence, "*very much*" is an [adverb of degree](http://www.english4today.com/englishgrammar/grammar/adverbs_degree.php), explaining *how much* the speaker wishes (or "might wish") to say the opposite.

To answer your question: **no**, this is not a non-native construction; it is grammatical. The use of "I'd rather say *X*" as opposed to "I would say *X*" implies a degree of preference. The first has a connotation that, given the opportunity, you **will** say *X*, whereas the second implies that you might be convinced to say otherwise (but you would need convincing). The addition of "*very much*" further emphasizes the speaker's conviction.